# Finetuning the Universal Sentence Encoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, training-data

I am new to TensorFlow. I am using Universal Sentence Encoder for text similarity. I would like to finetune USE with my own corpus.

I currently have:

```
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2" 
embed = hub.Module(module_url, trainable=True)
```

According to [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/110), setting `trainable=True` will "expose the variables as trainable". However, I have no clue what these trainable variables are and how I can use them to finetune the USE with my own corpus.

Please, any guidance or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To finetune a pre-trained model is to allow it's weights to be updated in the downstream training task.

So you have 2 options:

1. `trainable=False`

   - this option will train quicker but the pretrained model weights will never be updated. A sentence embedding will look identical before and after your own training. Only your own model layers will have their weights changed by training.
2. `trainable=True`

   - this adds a computational burden to your training loop but will allow the weights of the embedder to become updated according to your task and training data. This *may* result in a more accurate final model

Comment: Yes, #2 is indeed what I am looking for. Can you kindly share how this can be achieved?

Comment: To clarify, I would like to see how this can be achieved programmatically.